# Minuit doesn't fit curve

Tags: python, curve-fitting, iminuit

I'm trying to fit a curve using minuit but it appears that the data are not fitted correctly to the curve. I suspect that it has something to do with the log in the function since once I remove the chiaf from chisquare function the values are fitted correctly. The problem is also the value am18 that comes out negative it corresponds to a mass and since all other values are positive it's really strange that this one is not.

```
import numpy as np
from iminuit import Minuit

#some constants
hc = 197.3269788
mssph = 685.78 
#some data and errors to fit
muds = np.array([ 
    81.96100485,  64.96427609,  38.15520137,  45.75992993,
    27.38344029,  23.41742996,  18.73586921,  18.07486749,
     9.20589292,   4.83878931,  72.17070899,  71.08083681,
    39.57647386,  31.63373626,  30.65363538,  26.50584842,
    19.33150992,  13.45482499,   3.86943831,  68.76598171,
    66.7933219 ,  38.86139831,  38.61246743,  38.6500419 ,
    16.62670414,  16.24156579,   9.16347451,  52.48804692,
    51.95712296,  23.86333781,  23.81815279,  12.44282442
    ]) #xdata
Fr = np.array([ 
    127.31527434,  122.72790265,  110.26449558,  112.75717699,
    104.81830088,  104.35746903,  101.32016814,  100.54513274,
     96.87942478,   92.98330088,  124.9736053 ,  122.52414305,
    112.47114172,  108.74591788,  107.34258013,  108.00597616,
    102.18850331,  100.04522384,   91.47210596,  128.18641113,
    122.15516847,  108.23229985,  109.85263369,  107.69218856,
     99.14042658,   98.0902102 ,   99.1104204 ,  112.47678261,
    110.39126087,   98.373     ,   98.97391304,   95.01495652
    ])#ydata
Zsrgi = np.array([1.47, 1.5, 1.54, 1.58])

dzs = np.array([ 3.60555128,  3.60555128,  4.24264069,  1.41421356])
Za = np.array([ 0.9468,  0.9632,  0.9707,  0.9756])

Zaey = np.array([56.0, 53.0, 35.0, 15.0])

dmfel = np.array([ 
     2743.82452989,  1388.6310737 ,   689.77566743,   652.7213305 ,
     348.31861265,   309.31427565,   134.12993165,   157.95193019,
      60.83965035,    19.80905202,  3482.5565895 ,  3378.1685061 ,
     949.07161448,   570.68604168,   492.42222648,   801.32561084,
     362.30696375,   152.61749342,    26.39235787,  2733.32712033,
    2329.20044751,   788.45797536,   754.06472854,  1098.9552043 ,
     279.63806125,   213.46692781,   169.87677303,  2181.08350448,
    2018.45039786,   696.73902333,   763.51325268,   416.74304481
    ])
af = np.array([ 
    0.0575465 ,  0.05547301,  0.04983955,  0.05096624,  0.04737787,
    0.04716958,  0.04579672,  0.0454464 ,  0.0437895 ,  0.04202845,
    0.04717754,  0.04625286,  0.04245786,  0.04105158,  0.04052182,
    0.04077226,  0.03857616,  0.03776707,  0.03453072,  0.0414683 ,
    0.0395172 ,  0.03501315,  0.03553733,  0.03483842,  0.03207193,
    0.03173218,  0.03206222,  0.03104359,  0.03046799,  0.02715095,
    0.0273168 ,  0.02622413
    ])
afe = np.array([ 
    0.00039571,  0.00046823,  0.00034898,  0.00071523,  0.00052648,
    0.00051809,  0.00072373,  0.00059257,  0.00054912,  0.00065308,
    0.000283  ,  0.00028516,  0.00031909,  0.0003537 ,  0.00035294,
    0.0002573 ,  0.00034244,  0.00034139,  0.00055726,  0.00038002,
    0.00044435,  0.00050214,  0.00052077,  0.00037143,  0.00036278,
    0.00045654,  0.00039068,  0.00025011,  0.00024068,  0.00031897,
    0.00037707,  0.0003581
    ])
amssr = np.array([ 
        0.35006,  0.34592,  0.33967,  0.3175 ,  0.31341,  0.34965,
        0.33393,  0.31033,  0.30807,  0.32813,  0.29895,  0.26546,
        0.29559,  0.29298,  0.26026,  0.29264,  0.29094,  0.29074,
        0.25928,  0.3888 ,  0.23213,  0.23284,  0.22768,  0.20825,
        0.22591,  0.20437,  0.22353,  0.2036 ,  0.18987,  0.20088,
        0.18743,  0.18801
        ])
amudr = np.array([
    0.01737619,  0.01377279,  0.00808912,  0.00970136,  0.00580544,
    0.00496463,  0.00397211,  0.00383197,  0.0019517 ,  0.00102585,
    0.01227267,  0.01208733,  0.00673   ,  0.00537933,  0.00521267,
    0.00450733,  0.00328733,  0.002288  ,  0.000658  ,  0.00950714,
    0.00923442,  0.00537273,  0.00533831,  0.00534351,  0.0022987 ,
    0.00224545,  0.00126688,  0.00588165,  0.00582215,  0.00267405,
    0.00266899,  0.0013943
    ])
amudre = np.array([
     8.75479519e-04,   7.34296720e-04,   4.51927448e-04,
     5.98343236e-04,   3.81187530e-04,   3.18993055e-04,
     4.05218892e-04,   3.28835732e-04,   2.14302222e-04,
     1.80198850e-04,   6.27776371e-04,   6.18193827e-04,
     3.56742512e-04,   3.04857443e-04,   3.08046099e-04,
     2.32852126e-04,   1.84120801e-04,   1.62566426e-04,
     7.02801597e-05,   5.87470469e-04,   5.70265978e-04,
     3.42904960e-04,   3.42757519e-04,   3.31231953e-04,
     1.52175013e-04,   1.61067797e-04,   8.21035930e-05,
     1.40038557e-04,   1.42199518e-04,   7.54950814e-05,
     7.13899224e-05,   3.64415759e-05
     ])
mse = np.array([ 
    0.00049366,  0.00064125,  0.00045706,  0.00094021,  0.0009005 ,
    0.00074027,  0.00093984,  0.00068264,  0.00086371,  0.00083934,
    0.0004669 ,  0.00043174,  0.00057567,  0.00059908,  0.00064938,
    0.0005022 ,  0.00082   ,  0.00090521,  0.00106902,  0.00073246,
    0.00075007,  0.00098326,  0.0011934 ,  0.0006229 ,  0.00081216,
    0.00058873,  0.00052038,  0.00055326,  0.0005316 ,  0.00088051,
    0.00105233,  0.00053235
    ])

a = np.array([ 0.0904,  0.0755,  0.0647,  0.0552])

B = 2.61
Fc = 92.8
def Ffitr(X, s, pp, k, B=2.61, Fc=92.8, mu=770, Za=0.9468): #fit function
    logBXmu = np.log( (2 * B * X) / mu**2)
    temp1 = (2 * B * X) / (4 * pi * Fc)**2
    temp2 = temp1 * (afij[0] + 
                     afij[1] * logBXmu)
    temp3 = temp1**2*( afij[2] + 
                       afij[3] * logBXmu + 
                       afij[4] * logBXmu**2)
    temp4 = temp1**3 * (afij[5] + 
                        afij[6] * logBXmu + 
                        afij[7] * logBXmu**2 +
                        afij[8] * logBXmu**3)
    return Fc * pp * (1 + k * s) * (1 + temp2 + temp3 + temp4)

#chisquare
def chiwork( a0, a1, a2, a3,
             b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, 
             b10, b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, b17, b18, b19, 
             b20, b21, b22, b23, b24, b25, b26, b27, b28, b29, 
             b30, b31,
             z0, z1, z2, z3, za0, za1, za2, za3,
             am0, am1, am2, am3, am4, am5, am6, am7, am8, am9, 
             am10,am11, am12, am13, am14, am15, am16, am17, am18, am19,
             am20, am21, am22, am23, am24, am25, am26, am27, am28, am29,
             am30, am31,
             k, y1):
    B = 2.61
    Fc = 92.8
    hc = 197.3269788
    mu = 770
    ana = np.array([a0, a1, a2, a3])
    zs = np.array([z0, z1, z2, z3])
    za = np.array([za0, za1, za2, za3])
    am = np.array([am0, am1, am2, am3, am4, am5, am6, am7, am8, am9, 
                   am10, am11, am12, am13, am14, am15, am16, am17, am18, am19, 
                   am20, am21, am22, am23, am24, am25, am26, am27, am28, am29, 
                   am30, am31])
    #am[numpy.isnan(am)] = 10**(-50)
    am[am <= 0] = 10**(-50)
    bss = np.array([b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9,
                    b10, b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, b17,b18,b19, 
                    b20, b21, b22, b23, b24, b25, b26, b27, b28, b29,
                    b30, b31])
    betalat = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
               3, 3]
    chia = sum( ( (ana - a) / (ast  * 10**(-4) ) )**2)  +\
           sum(  ( (bss * a[betalat] / hc - amssr) / mse )**2)
    chiz = sum( ( (zs - 1 / Zsrgi) / (dzs * 10**(-2) ) )**2) +\
           sum( ( (za - Za) / (Zaey * 10**(-4) ) )**2)
    chiamd = sum( ( (amudr  - (1 + y1 * ana[betalat]**2) *
                     ana[betalat] * am * zs[betalat] / hc) / amudre)**2)
    chiaf = sum( ( ( af - Ffitr(am, bss**2 - mssph**2, ana[betalat] / 0.95, k) / hc) / afe)**2)
    return chia + chiz + chiamd + chiaf

#minuit part
mc=minuit.Minuit(
           chiwork, a0=0.09, z0=0.68, za0=0.95, am0=62,
                    b0=755, k=5.124105506705958e-07, y1=1,
                    error_a0=0.02, error_z0=0.02,
                    error_za0=0.02, error_am0=13, error_b0=4,
                    error_k=10**(-8), error_y1=0.1,errordef=1
                 )

fminc, paramc = mc.migrad()

print(mc.values)

#gtting values to plot
asp = []
bs = []
Zs = []
zas = []
mdus = []

for i in range(4):
    asp.append(mc.values[i])
for i in range(4, 36):
    bs.append(mc.values[i])
for i in range(36, 40):
    Zs.append(mc.values[i])
for i in range(40, 44):
    zas.append(mc.values[i])
for i in range(44,76):
    mdus.append(mc.values[i])
anna = np.array(asp)
bna = np.array(bs)
Zsn = np.array(Zs)
zasn = np.array(zas)
mduss = np.array(mdus)
mnew = np.linspace(min(mduss), max(mduss), 100)
bnew = np.linspace(min(bna), max(bna), 100)
annas = np.linspace(min(anna), max(anna), 100)
zasns = np.linspace(min(zasn), max(zasn), 100)
zsn = np.linspace(min(Zsn), max(Zsn), 100)

plt.figure(figsize=( 14, 8.5))
plt.ylim(90, 200)
plt.plot(muds, Fr, "b^")
plt.plot()
plt.plot(mnew, Ffitr(mnew, bnew**2 - mssph**2, annas  / zasns, mc.values["k"]) / annas)
```

What I get:

[image: Fit curve from the fitted data, dots are actual data points that I want the curve to follow.]

Comment: If you need a parameter to be positive, while the general fit does allow for negative values as well, change the formula to `parameter**2`. The fact that the algorithm is allowed to pass negative values might also be the problem with your `log`. The moment it gets a negative argument you get a complex answer and the procedure fails....just a guess. Finally, it is really hard to read your code. try to use some white space.

Comment: ...how many parameters do you actually want to fit....from how many data points?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, I solved it by making the chiwork take an array with parameters as arguements and used my data points as initial values and that solved it. There are more data points than parameters so that's not an issue.